# A Global Variable(State) in AWS for Serverless Orchestration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am writing a syncing/ETL app inside AWS. It works as follows:

- The source of the data is outside of AWS
- Whenever new data is changed/added AWS is alerted via API Gateway (REST)
- The REST API triggers a lambda function that does ETL and stores the data in CSV format to S3

This works fine for small tables. However, we are dealing with larger amount of data lately and I have to switch to Fargate (EKS/ECS) instead of lambda. As you can imagine these will be long running jobs and not cheap to perform. Usually when the data is changed in it changes multiple times within a period of 5 minutes, say for example 3 times. So REST API gets a ping 3 times in a row and triggers the ETL jobs 3 times as well. This is very inefficient as you can imagine.

I came up with idea that every time that REST API is triggered lets wait for 5 minutes if the API has not been invoked during the waiting period do ETL otherwise do nothing. I think I can do the waiting using Step Functions. However I cannot find a suitable way to store hash/id of the latest ping to API to one single variable. I thought maybe I can store the hash to an S3 object and after 5 minutes check to see if it is the same as the variable in my step function, but apparently ordinality is not guaranteed. I looked into SQS but the fact that is a FIFO is not very convenient and way more than what I actually need. I am pretty sure that other people have had a similar issue and there must a standard solution for this problem. I could not find any by googling and hence my plea here

Thanks

Comment: Api Gateway can invoke Step function and first step of the step function can write a record to dynamoDb, wait for 5 minutes and the the next step which can check if there is another entry for the api and decide to skip or move forward with ETL ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, [Amazon DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) is the store you are looking for to save the state of your job.

Also, please note that SQS is not [FIFO by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html). Using SQS won't prevent you from storing your job state.

What I would do:

- Trigger a job and store the state in DynamoDB. Do not further launch job until the job state is `done`.
- Orchestrate the ETL from Step Functions (including the 5 minutes wait)

You can also [expire](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) your jobs so DynamoDB will automatically clean them up with time.